# Convert base to bases within 2 to 9

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, radix

Okay so I am lost and stuck on how to make any further progress.
This program will return the value of the user inputted base into a list like this [1, 2, 2].
I am trying to do two things. First, instead of a single number like

```
userInt = 50
```

I want to be able to input

```
userList = [50, 3, 6, 44]
```

and then have the formula convert each number to the correct base.

So if I converted this to a base 6, I would want the result to be:

```
userNewList = [122, 3, 10, 112]
```

I've tried this with a for loop but can't get it right and end up just throughing an int is not iterable type error.

```
def baseConversion(userInt, base):
    remList = []
    while(userInt > 0):
        remList.append(userInt % base)
        userInt = userInt // base     
    return (remList[::-1])       


def main():
    base = int(input('Enter a base: '))
    userInt = 50
    remList = baseConversion(userInt, base)
    baseConversion(userInt, base)
    print(remList)
main()
```

I appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: Your code does not have a for loop and does not raise any errors for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python 2.7, but you can get the idea:

```
>>> def baseConversion(userInt, base):
        remList = ''
        while(userInt > 0):
            remList += str(userInt % base)
            userInt = userInt // base
        return int(remList[::-1]) # If you are just printing, you don't need to convert to int.

>>> def main():
        base = int(raw_input('Enter a base:'))
        userInt = [int(s.strip()) for s in raw_input('Enter numbers (comma separated):').split(',')]
        result = [baseConversion(i, base)  for i in userInt]
        print result


>>> main()
Enter a base:6
Enter numbers (comma separated):50,3,6,44
[122, 3, 10, 112]
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you. But one thing I need to do is to have it work with a list that is already completed, in this case i'll be pulling the list from a text document. So there won't be any user input. It doesn't seem like that difficult of a thing to change to, but I can't seem to get it.

Comment: How the inputs are stored in the file?

Comment: No, I have the file management down. I'm just trying to do what you showed me with a static list, not one determined by user input.

Comment: If the file has only comma separated numbers (no new line) you can just read the file and get your list like: `userInt = [int(s.strip()) for s in open('your_file.txt').read()]`